# How do you remove the handle of this faucet?

Tags: leak, faucet

I'm trying to fix a leak coming from the hot water handle of this faucet. Taking off the knob was easy enough but the cartridge it still hidden within the handle-- no set screw that I can see. The nut under the sink is also sunk pretty deep-- do I need to use some kind of basin wrench in this style? [https://www.amazon.com/Installer-Multifunctional-Bathroom-Extra-long-Plumbing/dp/B096VJKKFL/ref=sr_1_3_sspa?keywords=plumbing+open+end+basin+wrench&qid=1699217207&s=power-hand-tools&sr=1-3-spons&sp_csd=d2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9hdGY&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B096VJKKFL)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you will need to do is remove the chrome bell cover.

If you cannot turn it with your hands you will need a [rubber strap wrench](https://www.temu.com/kuiper/dn9.html?subj=downloadable-ads-shopping&_bg_fs=1&_p_jump_id=841&_x_vst_scene=adg&goods_id=601099513889998&sku_id=17592199717609&adg_ctx=a-11b2fc4f%7Ec-b22066e9%7Ef-b43b0638&_x_ads_sub_channel=shopping&_p_rfs=1&_x_ns_prz_type=3&_x_ns_sku_id=17592199717609&mrk_rec=1&_x_ads_channel=google&_x_gmc_account=700351367&_x_login_type=Google&_x_ads_account=1919904652&_x_ads_set=20515639425&_x_ads_id=152435010199&_x_ads_creative_id=672863011659&_x_ns_source=g&_x_ns_gclid=Cj0KCQjw-pyqBhDmARIsAKd9XIOHtp6cXi06GyBPI2tz7KISdH4N67xU3plgwE95gZt7BtGNDFYufBkaAvxgEALw_wcB&_x_ns_placement=&_x_ns_match_type=&_x_ns_ad_position=&_x_ns_product_id=700351367-17592199717609&_x_ns_target=&_x_ns_devicemodel=&_x_ns_wbraid=CjgKCAjw15eqBhBCEigAfk9orZK8Ht30DaLegA4rjLBvQXQTEeKceybMQ2XmmvKkbpnef5IMGgL9ng&_x_ns_gbraid=0AAAAAo4mICG1etn4kTSdHIx0QOFmriuYi&_x_ns_targetid=pla-370819644410&gclid=Cj0KCQjw-pyqBhDmARIsAKd9XIOHtp6cXi06GyBPI2tz7KISdH4N67xU3plgwE95gZt7BtGNDFYufBkaAvxgEALw_wcB).
Then you can get to the nut to remove the cartridge/stem.